# How to interpret javascript BN object?

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, truffle, bignum

While I was working on smart contract using truffle, whenever request some number like account balance or address from the truffle console; I receive a BN object which looks like this:

```
BN {
  negative: 0,
  words: [ 37748736, 3305132, 2220446, <1 empty item> ],
  length: 3,
  red: null
}
```

This object is part of [bn.js](http://0x1515434073111777e9b25534495063C98347d831) library. But I am not able to find any documentation on how to interpret this object.

How do I read this. I want to learn what each field in this object means and be able to manually convert it to a normal number.

Comment: what is this BN object? That's not a javascript built in - does [this documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#bn) help

Comment: If you are receiving a BN object already, probably you just need to use needed methods to get the number value: bn.toString(base, length), bn.toNumber(), etc

Comment: I would guess it is [this](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/) library.

Comment: The number represented appears to 10000000000000000000000. But this is based on analyzing the *current* internals of the source code. This can change over time, thus you should always use the methods suggested by @Eddy

Answer (score 4):

I am a bit late, but you can convert your function outcome like the following:

```
outcome = await app.balanceOf(0x....)
outcome.toNumber()
```

or even better:

```
(await app.balanceOf(0x....)).toNumber()
```

Answer (score 1):

`bn.js` has a [readme](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js) with examples.

You can convert the BN object to JS native `Number` using the `.toNumber()` function.